# How do you express reverse chaining in a HAPI FHIR Plain server

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

How do we support a query like

```
GET /base/ResearchStudy?_count=1&_has:ResearchSubject:study:individual=Patient/3635973&_elements=id
```

using HAPI FHIR plain server? The [documentation tells how to do chaining](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/rest_operations_search.html#chained-resource-references), but not [reverse chaining (`_has`)](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#has).

Answer (score 0):

This is another [search parameter](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/apidocs/hapi-fhir-base/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/param/package-summary.html), a [HasParam](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/apidocs/hapi-fhir-base/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/param/HasParam.html). There are also [HasAndListParam](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/apidocs/hapi-fhir-base/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/param/HasAndListParam.html) and [HasOrListParam](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/apidocs/hapi-fhir-base/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/param/HasOrListParam.html) variants.

*Example*:

```java
@Search()
public List<ResearchStudy> searchByHas(@RequiredParam(name=Constants.PARAM_HAS) HasParam has) {

  final var paramName = has.getParameterName();
  final var paramVal = has.getParameterValue();
  final var fieldName = has.getReferenceFieldName();
  final var targetType = has.getTargetResourceType();
   
   List<ResearchStudy> retVal = new ArrayList<Patient>();
   // ...populate...
   return retVal;
}
```